# Json.parse not executing script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"<script>alert(1)<//script>" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As we all know Json.parse converts string to Javascript object when i try to render the script tag from the java script it's is breaking not executing the script. Any Idea why it's not working.

Comment: This is by design. It would be a security flaw if this was possible. A better approach would be to store the value to be shown in its own property then call `alert(obj.employees[1].lastname)` after you have parsed the JSON

Comment: innerHTML doesn't execute javascript

Comment: When i try to execute . It's breaking i am expecting to print Anna <script>alert(1)<//script>" . It just printing Anna the throwing error as Illegal cgarcter